# Setting .htaccess for 404 error

Tags: php, .htaccess

So, I new to .htaccess.
My current .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /simpleblogsys/profile.php?username=$1
```

So I have created login and registration for the site I'm testing.
If I type username after 'simpleblogsys/', it directs to the page. 
Example:

```
http://localhost/simpleblogsys/TestUser1
```

The problem is, if I put a slash the username and type something random, 
Like this:

```
http://localhost/simpleblogsys/TestUser1/blablabla
```

it loads the page without any scripts or stylesheets. I want to setup a Error 404 document if the page wasn't found. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scripts and Stylesheets are not found most likely because you are calling them with a relative path...

```
js/whatever.js
```

you'll need to use a path from the root...

```
/assets/js/whatever.js
```

For the 404, if you are not seeing a valid username you can call:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
```